# How to display fetched data in a div container using React

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

I am fetching data using an API which is working fine. I am able to view the response. But I want to display the fetched data in div tag so that whatever is fetched will be rendered to these div tags. To do that I am saving the response into an array (as the response is a list) and then loading that array's elements in div. But I am seeing blank text in my div element. Where am I going wrong?

**Here is the code written in React:**

```
import Head from "next/head";
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import Nav from "./nav";
//import express from "../node_modules/express/index";
import categories from "./API1_getCategories";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  let response = [];
  
  //const [Elec,setElec] = useState("");
    return(
      <> 
     <Head>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/general.css"></link>
     </Head>
  
      <div>
      <div className="searchbardiv">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search"></input>
        <a href="./jewellery"><img src="./images/cart.png" typ></img></a>
        <a href="./electronics"><img src="./images/avatar.jpg"></img></a>
        
        </div>
      <div className="categories">
        <div> <button
        type="submit"
        onClick={() => {
          fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products/categories')
          .then(res=>res.json())
          .then(json=>{
            console.log(json);
            response=json;
            console.log(response);
          })
         
        }}
        
        >Show categories</button></div>
        <div>{response[0]} </div>
        <div> {response[1]}</div>
        <div>{response[2]}</div>
        <div> {response[3]}</div>

      </div>
      
      <div className="homepageproducts">
      
      <div>prod1</div>
      <div>prod2</div>
      <div>prod3</div>
      <div>prod4</div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </>
    )
    }
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mutating variable inside App. Never mutate anything!
Save response in state instead:

```
const [response, setResponse] = useState();
...
...fetch (...)
...
.then (
    ...
    setResponse(json);
)
```

....

and in render do more safe referencing to array elements or check if response is not empty:

```
 <div>{response?.[0]} </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The react-way to do is to make a state to store your response data. This is because everytime the components render it will rewrite the `response` variable.

```
  const [response, setResponse] = useState([]);

  const fetchCategories = () => {
    fetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products/categories")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => setResponse(json));
  };
```

I've done your example in the playground here: https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-lake-0ruiz1?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Yes, I can use states but how do I display the current state of the variable in a div? The div just has text in it. so what should be written inside div tag to display the set state of a variable?

Comment: I am unsure what your question is. Are you able to give an example ?